# Sharepoint REST - Delete item from list

Tags: rest, sharepoint

i would like to delete item from list in SharePoint 2016. I use SharePoint REST API, but I cannot successfully delete item. This is error message (http code 400):

> A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry.A 'StartObject' node was expected.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://myshp.com/test/_api/web/lists(guid'e23e21c7-ab29-445e-87b8-2b20b721f79d')/items?$filter=ID eq '5'',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            headers: {
                "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "DELETE"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

What is incorrect? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code: It works fine for me :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myshp.com/test/_api/web/lists(guid'e23e21c7-ab29-445e-87b8-2b20b721f79d')/items(5)",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```